# Why jQuery transit doesn't work on mobile?

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, jquery-transit

I am using this syntax:

```
var slidesContainerElem = jQuery('.elementContainer');
var currSlideElem = jQuery('.element');
slidesContainerElem.transition({ x: -currSlideElem.position().left },750);
```

It works perfectly on desktop, but it fails on mobile. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out.
I think someone may face the same problem. It's simple:

```
slidesContainerElem.transition({ x:-currSlideElem.position().left },750);
```

You have to remove the space between colon and minus sign